# Passing variables (that have space) using JavaScript window pop-up

Tags: javascript, php

Pop-up script:

```
<script>
function myFunction2(url,url2) {

window.open('googleapi.php?id='+url+'&id2='+url2, "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=70,left=50,width=1200,height=500");
}

</script>
```

PHP code:

```
echo "<td style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>" . '<a style="color: 
red;font-weight: bold;" href= javascript:myFunction2("'."tom
peter".'","'.$row['Account_Number'].'")>'.'Abnormal'.'</a>' . "</td>";
```

Error - it's only considering "tom" - `myFunction2("tom`

I need to obtain `myFunction2("tom peter","11234")` - Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one, you will get result as you expect.

```
echo "<td style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>" . "<a style='color: 
red;font-weight: bold;' href= javascript:myFunction2('".rawurlencode('tom peter')."','".$row['Account_Number']."')>"."Abnormal"."</a>" . "</td>";
```

Comment: Piyush i have checked and its not working..

Comment: Edited my answer added encode function, try now..

Comment: Awesome. it worked you saved my day!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php
$row['Account_Number']=12345;
$link="<a style='color: red;font-weight: bold;' href=javascript:'myFunction2(".urlencode('tom peter').",".$row['Account_Number'].")'>Abnormal</a>";
echo "<td style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>" .$link. "</td>"; 
?>
```

because of space in your perameter it will not pass whole perameter value so using `urlencode` and `urldecode` you get the value which will have apace

Answer (score 0):

Change php code as :

```
<?php 
$acNumb = "11234";
echo "<td style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'><a style='color: red;font-weight: bold;' href= 'javascript:myFunction2(".'"tom peter"'.",".'"'.$acNumb.'"'.")'>Abnormal</a></td>"; 
?>
```